# htmlUnit - clicking a button

Tags: java, button, htmlunit

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure it out, testing etc but I can't get it to work.
Basically, I want it to click a button (not js) with text "Enter a". No text like that is found other where.

Code for the button:

```
<div class="votebox">
   <span class="votehead"> </span>
   <br><br>
   <a href="http://www.link-where-it-redirects.com" class="cssbuttongo">Enter a</a><br><br><br>
   <span class="votehead"> </span>
  </div>
```

How can I make it so it will click that button?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't click a button is that there is no button but rather an anchor. There are many ways to get that anchor but probably the easier one would be using [`getAnchorByText(String)`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getAnchorByText%28java.lang.String%29) this way:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://yourpage.com");
HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByText("Enter a");
page = anchor.click();
```

If I didn't commit any syntactical error while typing that then that would do the trick.